# how do i get text from QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

so basically i just started to learn PyQt and I want to get element's text in listWidget, but everytime i try self.listWidget.currentItem().text() it throws an error. Why?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QListWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainPage(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainPage,self).__init__()
        loadUi("HomePage.ui",self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addToList)
        self.selectButton.clicked.connect(self.getText)



    def addToList(self):
        customername = self.plainTextEdit_16.toPlainText()
        self.listWidget.addItem(customername)



    def getText(self):
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem().text() ##error is here

        print(item)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = MainPage()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: You should show the error you get when you are asking a question.
Also, don't make all of your text **bold**.

Comment: What is `HomePage.ui`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that "addToList" runs correctly then the only error is that there is no item selected so the currentItem will return None. The solution is to verify that it is None:

```py
def getText(self):
    item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
    if item is not None:
        print(item.text())
```

Comment: Thanks. Should be`item.text()` instead of `it.text()`